# RequestBody is null in all POST requests since upgrading to Play 2.5 from 2.4

Tags: java, android, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am sending data from an Android application using Retrofit 2, and everything worked fine, but since chanaging my Play project to v2.5 to avail of the JPAApi any request body received in my API is null. Below is an example controller where I am experiencing this problem.

```
    @Transactional
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    @AddCSRFToken
    public Result register() {
        if (request().body() == null) {
            return badRequest();
        }

        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

        String email = json.path("email").asText();
        String password = json.path("password").asText();

        if (repo.findByEmail(email) != null) {
            return status(CONFLICT);
        }

        User user = new User(email, hashPassword(password));
        String authToken = user.createAuthToken();
        response().setCookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
        return ok(Json.toJson(repo.insert(user)));
    }
```

Comment: What is the payload of the request?